# Jmeter Rampup based on Timings

Tags: jmeter

I dont know i can able to acheive this or not, I have scenario where i need to rampup based on timings(seconds)
example : Rampup 10 users on 1st second, rampup 20 users on 2nd second, rampup 50users on 3rd second, rampup 0 users on 4th second, rampup 100 users on 5th second, i need to continue this for 5 hours, seconds by seconds rampup, is there anyway i can parametrize jp@gc ultimate thread group?

is there any way to acheive this through scripting in jmeter?

Please throw some light on this

Regards,
Shinelog

Answer (score 0):

Please add the Stepping Thread Group/Concurrency Thread Group at test plan.  Manage the ramp up time & threads accordingly.